# Import existing java project in eclipse but design view not exist for JFrame?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I import  existing java project in eclipse:
in eclipse:
1. go to **File** -> **Import**
2. **General** -> **Existing Projects into Workspace** and click **Next**

[image]

3.click on **Browse** and select project then click on **Finish**

[image]

then i open a JFrame , but i see source code of JFrame and design tab not exist.

[image]

how to view Design tab?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found a solution:

in **Package Explorer** right click on JFrame file then select **Open With** -> **WindowBuilder Editor**

[image]

now design tab appeared

[image]

Comment: Yes, awful code that I would never want to have to touch.  Samiey, you were better off before without the tab.

Comment: Also you can set an editor as default for a type of file. Go to general>editors>file associations. Hope that helps